# tableview doesn't see the title for header in section method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was trying to create a custom `viewForHeaderInSection` for my `tableview.Tableview` itself
    works fine, but for some reason, compiler skips,

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{}
```

Delegate method, and I tried what is written on the reference , and this .But for some reason it just doesn't read these methods. Obviously, I am doing something wrong. If someone can point my mistake out, I would appreciate. Thank you in advance.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize settingTableView,audioPlayer,labelSwitch,descriptiveSwitch,autoPlaySwitch;;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.settingTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    self.settingTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    settings = @{@"Animation Sets" : @[@"Set1",@"Set2",@"Set3"],@"Settings" : @[@"Label",@"Sound",@"Autoplay"]};
    values = [[settings allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

    [settingTableView setRowHeight:44];
    [settingTableView reloadData];

}

-(void)close:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.delegate closeView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [values count];
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [values objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [values objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionValue = [settings objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionValue count];
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
    NSString *value = [values objectAtIndex:section];

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]init];

    //if (section == 0 && section == 1) {

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        title.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,150,30);
    }
    else
    {
        title.frame = CGRectMake(10,5,100,30);
    }

    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    title.text = value;

    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:title];
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    //}
    return headerView;
    [settingTableView reloadData];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;

    static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

        NSString *sectionTitle = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *sectionValue= [settings objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        NSString *settingValues = [sectionValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = settingValues;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the code to find the where you were wrong

Comment: i have added the code above.Please check

Comment: remove this line' [settingTableView reloadData];' in the viewforheaderinsection

Comment: removed,but still the problem not solve.kindly help

Comment: can you scroll the tableview

Comment: yes,i have checked with scroll,but not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the class that implements that delegate method is the `delegate` and `dataSource` of your table view.

Comment: Yes,i have implements the delegate and datasource methods in .h file and also facing the above problem.

Comment: The contents of the cell and everything works fine? What do you have inside `titleForHeaderInSection`?

Comment: cell for row working fine only the titleForHeaderInSection method not call when compile.
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return [values objectAtIndex:section];
}

Comment: Yes, what do you have inside it? Can you put the content of the method there?

Comment: (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [values objectAtIndex:section]; }

Comment: Please update your question above. Is the return value a string? Can you try putting `return @"Hello";`?

Comment: return value is getting,but the title for header in section method doesn't call.it is the only problem.